# Implement bearer token authentication for azure functions

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I have a few azure functions that I would like to set a token based authentication (using a bearer token). I would like to make sure that users that does not pass in a bearer token in the HTTP header, is not able to access the azure function. I am using visual code/Azure cloud. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I have a way to obtain the bearer token using the client id, secret, tenant id, however how would I make it a required field for an azure function?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case, you just need to enable the azure ad auth for your function app.

Navigate to the function app -> `Authentication / Authorization` -> follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings) to configure the azure ad auth(recommend you to choose `Create New AD App` like below, it will automatically configure several settings for you and reduce some issues).

[image]

After configuring the app, select the `Log in with Azure Active Directory`.

[image]

> I have a way to obtain the bearer token using the client id, secret, tenant id, however how would I make it a required field for an azure function?

After all the configuration, the access token is needed when you use the service principal(the client id, secret, tenant id stuff you mentioned, i.e. the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)) to access the function.

Comment: The data I would like to pull is from another AD tenant. I've used the advanced option to include the client ID, issuer URL, and secret. When I try running the azure function, now it is returning an internal server error 500. I figure I am imputting the Issuer URL incorrectly. Is there a way to check the issuer URL? Additionally, would I have to just input the bearer token in the header of the HTTP request to get authenticated?

Comment: @Jackrow102 What do you mean `The data I would like to pull is from another AD tenant`? You mean your function app is in tenant A, and your client AD App is in tenant B, you want to use the client app access the function?

Answer (score 0):

Function App ==> Settings ==> Authentication ==> “Add Identity Provider as Microsoft” and select “Already Created App” or “Create a New One”.

[image: Configure Authentication]

Then Call your Azure function from Postman

[image: Call Azure Function]